# Am I doing it wrong or django rest api framework / coreapi has a bug?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, core-api

I'm experiencing some troubles with coreapi and Django REST API. Perhaps someone can help me understand what is wrong.
On `update` and `partial_update` the schema returns the same fields twice. Here's an example:

```
        "update": {
            "_type": "link",
            "url": "/lindex/puddle/{name}/",
            "action": "put",
            "encoding": "application/json",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "name",  <-- Here 
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "path",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "description": "A unique value identifying this puddle.",
                        "title": "name"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "name", <-- Here
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "description": "",
                        "title": "Name"
                    }
                },
```

When coreapi does this call

```
create = client.action(schema, ['api', 'v1', 'puddleatom', 'update'],
    {   "name": "1NEW",
        #"names": "RAW_TR_BOS_CDR_201701-NEW",
        "ingestion_flow": "ING-RAW_TR_BOS_CDR",
        "status": "OK",
        "location": "hdfs://hdfs-prod/user/hive/warehouse/repl_jmailer_tr.db/bos_cdr_201701",
        "comment": "This atom contains data about BOS_CDR in 201701",
        "records": 29452695,
        "size": 2022540894,
        "files": 10,
        "puddle": "RAW_TR_BOS_CDR"
    })
```

the computed URL is wrong:

```
http://172.17.0.2:8000/api/v1/puddleatom/{name}/
```

This happens because the function `_get_params` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coreapi/transports/http.py`

allocates the parameters in the form but not in the path

```
key[status], value[OK]
location:form
key[comment], value[This atom contains data about BOS_CDR in 201701]
location:form

-------------------
name is processed just once into the _get_params function and the destination is the form 

key[name], value[1NEW]
location:form
--------------------


key[records], value[29452695]
location:form
key[puddle], value[RAW_TR_BOS_CDR]
location:form
key[ingestion_flow], value[ING-RAW_TR_BOS_CDR]
location:form
key[files], value[10]
location:form
key[size], value[2022540894]
location:form
key[location], value[hdfs://hdfs-prod/user/hive/warehouse/repl_jmailer_tr.db/bos_cdr_201701]
location:form
```

What could be wrong here? The `_get_params` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coreapi/transports/http.py` or the definition of the schema where the same fields is reported twice?